# Jmeter report giving errors with distributed mode but errors don`t appear in result tree

Tags: jmeter

I am running my test in distributed mode from the GUI.  I have some 20,000 users and two vitual machines have more than 4 VPCUs and 80 Gg memory.  I can`t see any stress on any of the machines, neither the slaves or masters, nor the server under test and I could hardly see any error in the GUI.  However, in the report, I am having the following errors:

> Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response
>   message: Couldn't kickstart handshaking
>
> Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response
>   message: readHandshakeRecord
>
> Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response
>   message: Connection reset

The errors are only 0.05%

Can anyone help me what these errors mean and how can I correct them.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not seeing the error in GUI because i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener shows only 500 last results, it is controllable by `view.results.tree.max_results` JMeter Property and if you add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   view.results.tree.max_results=0
   ```

   next time you run JMeter you will see each and every request in the View Results Tree listener.
2. Be informed that GUI mode should be used for tests development and debugging, [execution should happen in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. For `Couldn't kickstart handshaking` and `readHandshakeRecord`  - you can get some troubleshooting information by enabling debug logging for SSL, it can be done by adding the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=ssl
   ```
4. For `Connection reset` - see [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki article
5. If you have access to your application logs - check them for any suspicious entries

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)