# How to generate logs in jmeter when launching test from non-GUI

Tags: jmeter

I am doing load test using 5 slaves machines.  Upon reaching 50,000 users I am having connection reset errors and handshake errors.  I have followed the steps mentioned in [Jmeter report giving errors with distributed mode but errors don`t appear in result tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131883/jmeter-report-giving-errors-with-distributed-mode-but-errors-dont-appear-in-res/62135135#62135135)
and h[ttps://www.xtivia.com/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors/](https://www.xtivia.com/fixing-jmeter-socket-errors/)

When I use javax.net.debug=ssl, there is a long list appearing and it difficult to go through such a long list to find any error.

Can someone help with the different kinds of logs that can be generated and how to generate them as I am testing from non GUI mode.  I have read many posts and so far I have not been successful to find the cause of these errors.
Is it related with sockets recycle?  Is it from JMeter or the Client machines?

The errors are :
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response message: Couldn't kickstart handshaking
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response message: Connection reset
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response message: readHandshakeRecord

Answer (score 0):

```
jmeter -n -t sso.jmx > stdout.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks